# PHP Get all img tags from folder of HTML files in an HTML table. Add a Click feature on each row to allow modification

Tags: php, image, tags

I need help with a piece of code i've spent days trying to solve.

I have a folder "modules" with dozens of files which contain imag tags.
I need to fetch all image tags (scr / alt) from all the files and list them in a table with a link to edit the row like in the example below:

file                    scr                             alt          action
-------                 --------                        --------     -------

index.html    -         images/error.png       -        error   -    edit tags

products      -         images/product.jpg     -        product -    edit tags

When you click on 'edit', a popup open giving the user the option to edit the info. So far, i can get all the image tags listed in the table, but i dont know how to perform the edit. Could anyone pls help..thanks in advance.

Here's what ive done so far:

```
    //To get array of file with image tags from directory

    while (false !== ($file = $dir->read()))
    {   
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')
        {
            // Is this entry a file or directory?
            if (is_file($path . '/' . $file))
            {
                // Its a file, lets push the files in an array
                $files = ($path . '/' . $file);

               // a new dom object & load the html into the object
               $dom = new DOMDocument();
               $html_string = file_get_contents($files);
               @$dom->loadHTML($html_string);

               // return number of tags in page
               $numtag = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->length; 
               if($numtag>0)
               {
                   //put files with img tag in an array
                   $filewithimgtag[] = $files;
               }
           }    
       }
    }
    $dir->close();



    //To get the tags from each files

    foreach($filewithimgtag as $key=>$eachfilewithtag)
    {
        // load the html of files with img tag into the object
        $domm = new DOMDocument();
        $htmlstring = file_get_contents($eachfilewithtag);
        @$domm->loadHTML($htmlstring);

        // return number of tags in page
        $arraythis[$eachfilewithtag]['qty'][] = $domm->getElementsByTagName('img')->length;

        // return the tags in page
        $taggers = $domm->getElementsByTagName('img');

        $arrayImage[$key]['file'][] = $eachfilewithtag;

        foreach ($taggers as $tagger) 
        {
            $arrayImage[$key]['scr'][] .= $tagger->getAttribute('src');
            $arrayImage[$key]['alt'][] .= $tagger->getAttribute('alt');
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to get filename with src so you can easily find and change in single file and when editing image data just pass file path and index of img tag and get img tags from file till given index and update on that img tag

```
 foreach($filewithimgtag as $key=>$eachfilewithtag)
    {
        // load the html of files with img tag into the object
        $domm = new DOMDocument();
        $htmlstring = file_get_contents($eachfilewithtag);
        @$domm->loadHTML($htmlstring);

        // return the tags in page
        $taggers = $domm->getElementsByTagName('img');

        foreach ($taggers as $tagger) 
        {
            $arraythis[$eachfilewithtag]['images'][] = array(
               'src'=>$tagger->getAttribute('src'),
               'alt' =>$tagger->getAttribute('alt')
            )
        }

    }
```

iterate $arraythis it in table

```
 <table>
        foreach($arraythis as $file => $filesArr){
           foreach ($filesArr['images'] as $key => $image) {
              <tr><td>echo $image['src']</td><td>echo $image['alt']</td><td>got 
               to edit function($file, $key)</td></tr>
           }
        }
   </table>
    findimgetochangeData($file, $index){
         $domm = new DOMDocument();
         $htmlstring = file_get_contents($file)
         @$domm->loadHTML($htmlstring);
         $taggers = $domm->getElementsByTagName('img');
         // you can find your selected tag change data of $taggers[$index]
       }
```

Comment: Thank you Pavan. I got what u mean...im now trying to get the codes to work...will get back to you if you dont mind

Comment: Dear Pavan,

I manage to populate the html table with rows of all img tag found,
Got the ajax script to execute the php function findimgetochangeData($file, $index).

But i cant seem to be able to do the modication. Ive tried a series of ideas...but in vain

Comment: i cant you can find the selected tag to change the data.
$taggers[$indexImg] doesnt work

Comment: $indexImg will be the index of img tag in that file and you need to pass it when you click on table row

Comment: dont wanna be a bother, how would u go about getting the modif done?

Comment: heres how im passing it: <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadImageSEO('<?php echo $Picfichier; ?>', '<?php echo $Picsrc; ?>', '<?php echo $Picalt; ?>', '<?php echo $Pickey; ?>');">Modifier</a></td>

Pickey is the indexImg

Comment: now in your php code $domm = new DOMDocument();
        $htmlstring = file_get_contents($Picfichier);
        @$domm->loadHTML($htmlstring);
$taggers = $domm->getElementsByTagName('img');
$selectedImg = $taggers[$Pickey];
and update $selectedImg data and save file

Comment: $doc->saveHTML();

Comment: i guess I tried this, let me try it again..maybe i messed up somewhere.

thanks Pavan..

u r a lifesaver, man

Comment: Hey Pavan, ive got the function done..but it aint saving the scr

Comment: ive had to change:
 $selectedImg = $taggers[$Pickey] to $selectedImg = $taggers->item($img_index); 

$selectedImg->setAttribute('src', $newimgsrc);
$domm->saveHTML();

Comment: Ohk you are getting object not array of img tags. if its working now you can approve my answer if not an issue &#128521;&#128521;

Comment: can you tell what im doing wrong?

$img_files =  $_POST['nomfichier'];
 $img_index = $_POST['SEOImageKey';
 $domm = new DOMDocument(); 
 if($img_files<>""){
  $htmlstring = file_get_contents($img_files);
  @$domm->loadHTML($htmlstring);
 }
 $taggers = $domm->getElementsByTagName('img'); 
 if($img_index<>""){
  $selectedImg = $taggers->item($img_index); 
 }
 $newimgsrc =$_POST['imgsrc'];
 $newimgalt = $_POST['imgalt'];
 if($selectedImg<>"")
 {
  $selectedImg->setAttribute('src', $newimgsrc);
  $selectedImg->setAttribute('alt', $newimgalt);
  $domm->saveHTML($selectedImg);
 }

Comment: you know, ive reach this far because of you...Im new to stackexchange,....how to approve your answer?